# Strategy Pattern in Java 8

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to know if the following lines of code represent a valid implementation of Strategy Pattern in Java 8:

```
public interface AIStrategy {
    void play();
}



public class AIPlayer {

    private AIStrategy aiStrategy;

    public AIPlayer() {
    }

    public AIPlayer(AIStrategy aiStrategy) {
        this.aiStrategy = aiStrategy;
    }

    public void changeStrategy(AIStrategy aiStrategy) {
        this.aiStrategy = aiStrategy;
    }

    public void fight() {
        aiStrategy.play();
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AIPlayer aiPlayer = new AIPlayer();
        String difficulty;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        difficulty = sc.next();

        switch (difficulty) {
            case "chill":
                aiPlayer = new AIPlayer(()
                        -> System.out.println("The opponent is playing a chill strategy..."));
                aiPlayer.fight();
                break;
            case "calculated":
                aiPlayer = new AIPlayer(()
                        -> System.out.println("The opponent is playing a calculated strategy..."));
                aiPlayer.fight();
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Is the opponent hurt?");
        boolean isHurted = sc.nextBoolean();
        if (isHurted) {
            aiPlayer.changeStrategy(()
                    -> System.out.println("The opponent changed his strategy. Now he is having a holy rage!!"));
            aiPlayer.fight();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a good implementation of the strategy pattern. I don't know if the code you posted is just a simplification or not but I think that you have to prevent a *NullPointerException* when a client class doesn't specify the strategy to use. You can achieve this task in many ways, for example eliminating the empty constructor or inserting a default strategy in the empty constructor. Another elegant way would be making the strategy a parameter of the *fight()* method (obviously only if it used within the method):

```
public void fight(AIStrategy strategy) {
     strategy.player();
}
```

Making this way you will make the classes lighter, and it will be more difficult to get a *NullPointerException*.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AIPlayer aiPlayer = new AIPlayer();
        AIStrategy stragey = () -> System.out.println("Default strategy");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String difficulty = sc.next(); 
        switch (difficulty) {
            case "chill":
                strategy = () -> System.out.println("The opponent is playing a chill strategy...");
                break;
            case "calculated":
                strategy = () -> System.out.println("The opponent is playing a calculated strategy...");
                break;
        }
        aiPlayer.fight(strategy);
        System.out.println("Is the opponent hurt?");
        boolean isHurted = sc.nextBoolean();
        if (isHurted) {
            strategy = () -> System.out.println("The opponent changed his strategy. Now he is having a holy rage!!"));
            aiPlayer.fight();
        }
        aiPlayer.fight(strategy);
    }
}
```